# How to recover the lost data from NQ Vault

Tags: google-play-store

my phone got factory reset by mistake. I had very important data in my NQ Vault. Is there any possibility wherein I can recover it. 
Please note it was not the premium account. It was a basic one. Also online account was created however no backup was taken. Please please help me!

Can anyone please help!